# Why is this Regex not returning the desired match?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the following text:

```
data:{
                url: 'stage-player-stat'
            },
            defaultParams: {
                stageId: 9155,
                teamId: 32,
                playerId: -1,
                field: 2
            },
```

Using the Regex:

```
stagematch = re.compile('data:{url: \'ws-stage-stat\'},defaultParams: {},', re.S)
```

I am not getting a match using this however. To me it looks correct though. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it looks json-ish... do you really want handle it by regexes?

Comment: @JakubJirutka i've not been using Python for long and i've never used a JSON parser before.

Comment: @user3045351 Well, then you should read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html) first.

Comment: but first try get this piece of data, whatever it's source is to be valid json. You can check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Besides the deeper question of parsing JSON with a regexp, your regexp doesn't allow for white space between the components like "{" and "url:", nor all the text within `defaultParams: {}`.

And your regexp URL `'ws-stage-stat'` doesn't match the text's URL `'stage-player-stat'`.

The following matches your data. (Using a raw string literal is common for regexp patterns to avoid having to double the backslashes.)

```
stagematch = re.compile(
    r"data:\s*{\s*url:\s*'stage-player-stat'\s*},\s*defaultParams:\s*{.*},",
    re.S)
```

Comment: @jerry101 s, just humouring me for a minute, if you put re.M, you can then write a Regex across multiple lines?

Comment: The multiline option only changes the meaning of `^` and `$` anchors *(that means respectivly `begining of the line`, `end of the line`)* , that's all.

Comment: @user3045351 I added a pattern that matches your example data. @CasimirEtHippolyte I stand corrected about `re.M`. It's not needed here since this pattern has no `^` or `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons your regex is not returning the desired match:

1. **Your regex actually does not match**

   *`ws-stage-stat` ≠ `stage-player-stat`, so you won't get a match.

   ** Also take into account `non-word chars`, `multiple lines`, or `upper/lowercase`.
2. Using `match groups` will allow you to capture desired parts of string.

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do anyway. As others have said, it might be better to use a library or specific parser instead; I'm not one who advocates one thing or another — but the thing that works.

If you wanted to match your string (json?) using regex though, including other urls then you could do something like:

```
p = re.compile(ur'\'(.*)\'|(\w+):\s(.+(?=[,])|.+\n)')
list = re.findall(p, str)
print(list)
```

result:

```
[(u'', u'url', u"'stage-player-stat'\n"), (u'', u'defaultParams', u'{\n'), (u'', u'stageId', u'9155'), (u'', u'teamId', u'32'), (u'', u'playerId', u'-1'), (u'', u'field', u'2\n'), (u'', u'url', u"'ws-stat'\n"), (u'', u'defaultParams', u'{\n'), (u'', u'stageId', u'9155'), (u'', u'teamId', u'32'), (u'', u'playerId', u'-1'), (u'', u'field', u'2\n'), (u'', u'stageId', u'9155'), (u'', u'teamId', u'32'), (u'', u'playerId', u'-1')]
```